# JSP: Onclick code is being performed when on page load event occurs

Tags: javascript, jsp, onclick, onload

I ve written the following for displaying different rows and columns of a DB. and infront of every row, there is a Delete Button. 
Onclick of the Delete button should call a set of function/ perform the code written inside Onclick event(check below)..Now what's happening is when the JSP page is loading , its going inside the method. So if there are 3 rows,
it will invoke the method 3 times....HELP ! it should invoke these method only "ON CLICK" of Delete button...

```
      <tbody>    <% 
                int x;

                while(rs2.next()){
                    x=0;
                    %>
                    <tr><%
                    while(x<d)
                    {
                    x=x+1;
                 %>
            <td>  <%
                    out.print(rs2.getString(x));%></td>
            <% } %>
          <td> <input type="button" value="Delete" class="btn" id="DeleteBtn" onclick="<% System.out.print("Delete button"); tableupdateBean.setupdateRow(rs2.getString(x)); tableupdateBean.DeleteRow();%>" /> </td>
           </tr> 
            <% } %>
     </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick is client side event and you can only specify any javascript function which will be called when this event will occur. You can not specify any server side jsp/java function.

Comment: Hi Thanks ! How should i go about it if i need to call jsp/java function on the click of a button ?

Comment: onclick on a buttton, you need to call a javascript function which will send Ajax request to server, if you are using jquery you can see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your are mixing things between javascript and jsp scriptlet.

onclick is a javascript event that occurs when an element gets clicked, in this case a button.
 `onlick=""` should reference a javascript function but in your code sample you have a scriptlet.

Scriptlet are executed when the JSP is invoked, so when the page loads.

Comment: Great.Thanks ! I'm kind of new to this. ! Now, how can I involke my java/jsp scriplet functions on the event of onclick of the Delete button in the code above? Can u help please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct a delete url with an `Unique Id` to identify the deletion row from the server side and reload the full page again.

Client Side

```
<a href="/yoururl?mode=delete&id="+<Unique Id>>Delete Row</a>
```

Server Side

```
if("delete".equals(request.getParameter("mode"))
{
String id = request.getParameter("id");

// write code for deletion
}

//redirect to the same page again
```

If you don't want to reload the full page, then you have to write `ajax` calls to perform deletion in the server side and use `javascript` remove the row from the table